# how to call vuejs function from seperate javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

I am trying to call vuejs function from external javascript function,but its not calling, I have given below the code which i am trying.

//below is my vuejs code vu.js

```
            Ut = {
                    data: function() {
                    },
                    methods: {
                        show() {
                            alert("Succes");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

//below is my seperate js file ext.js

```
  function call(){
            show()
           }
```

Comment: Can you create this problem at any code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your vue component to your `ext.js` file

```
import Vu from '../vu'

function call(){
 Vu.show()
}
```